# How can you redefine a POD type such that it is considered a distinct type while maintaining the semantics?

Tags: c++, types

Imagine the following scenario where we have a pod container type that applies to many different scenarios:

```
struct vec2 {
  float x, y;
};
```

Some of these scenarios might be storing a velocity, a position, an acceleration, etc. Now suppose we want to be able to handle all these scenarios independently while putting the type system to work and also maintaining the semantics of `vec2`, i.e. `velocity.x`, `acceleration.y`, etc.:

```
struct Simulation {
    template<typename T>
    static void handle() { fprintf( stdout, "Generic handler\n" ); }
};

template<>
void Simulation::handle<vec2>() { fprintf( stdout, "generic vec2 handler\n" ); }

template<>
void Simulation::handle<position>() { fprintf( stdout, "position handler\n" ); }

template<>
void Simulation::handle<velocity>() { fprintf( stdout, "velocity handler\n" ); }

template<>
void Simulation::handle<acceleration>() { fprintf( stdout, "acceleration handler\n" ); }
```

In the above case using either `typedef` or `using` will not do the job as they do not affect the typeid of the alias as per the standard, so one cannot do:

```
using position = vec2;
```

The next attempt might be to try and inherit from the pod, i.e.:

```
struct position : public vec2 {}
```

however this has the disadvantage that `new` and `delete` are now broken as there is no virtual destructor on the pod type, and also the qualification of the `position` being a pod has been lost due to the inheritance.

Then it could be argued that simply copying and pasting the code for `vec2` and renaming it to the desired type would satisfy all the requirement, but there are also a couple of issues with this:

1. Copy-Pasting code is bad*
2. In the example above vec2 has no associated operators or anything like that, but any useful vec2 class would most certainly have this and copying and pasting while renaming the data structure in this case would be pretty error prone especially if a fix is required in one of the operators

The vec2 could also be encapsulated in the new type:

```
struct position {
  vec2 pos;
};
```

but this solution breaks the requirement for maintaining the semantics.

Another thing to note is that we might not have control over the implementation of vec2 (i.e. in the case where a library like GLM is used).

I feel that templating should provide the necessary solution, but can't work out how it would work. So the question is what is the correct way of going about redefining a type, while maintaining the semantics of the type, but ending up with a different type id?

*-not in all scenarios, but this one definitely

Comment: You might be trying too hard to reuse code. The semantics of `Position` and  `Velocity` are not the same at all, so what is there to reuse? If you subtract two posiions you get a distance, but what do you get if you subtract two velocities?

Comment: I agree that the semantics of `position` and `velocity` are not the same, but all the operations on the internal fields are the same, i.e. you can add velocities just as you can add positions, and in the case where you are using a library that handles linear algebra, you want to be able to reuse all the hard work that has been put into that

Comment: Since those are different quantities I agree they should have a different type. Since `vec2` can handle their representation in the reference space, each type should contain a `vec2 icoords;` accessible with `vec2& coords() noexcept {return icoords;}` or a `operator vec2&()` if the conversion should be transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps.

```
template <typename Tag>
struct vec2 {
  float x, y;
};

using position = vec2<struct PositionTag>;
using velocity = vec2<struct VelocityTag>;
```

`position` and `velocity` would have similar behavior, but are distinct types.

Comment: This would indeed be my preferred solution if I were to control the implementation of `vec2`, but unfortunately it can't be used reliably with library code, which is what I am looking to do

Comment: @Alex then use `template <typename tag> my_tagged_vec2 { vec2 data; }`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Please read the question post, it specifically states that it needs to maintain the semantics of the base data structure and there is literally no difference between your solution and just saying `struct position { vec2 data; };` which I have already discused

Comment: @Alex "So the question is [...], while maintaining the semantics of the type, but ending up with a different type id?" `vec2` has the same semantics (you cannot change it anyhow) and `my_tagged_vec2` is a different type. The difference to `struct position { vec2 data; }` is that you need to write one template instead of N types

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `vec2` obviously maintains its own semantics, but `my_tagged_vec2` has no member `x` or `y` and therefore does not maintain the same semantics

Comment: You seem to be saying that you have `someFunction(const vec2&)` (where `someFunction` stands for "associated operators or anything like that") and you want it to accept an instance of `position` as an argument, but have `position` be a distinct type. I can think of only two ways this could work: `position` publicly derives from `vec2`, or `position` provides a conversion operator `operator vec2&()` (e.g. returning a reference to its `vec2` data member).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That is exactly what I am saying. To a large extent I am leaning towards the `position` derives from `vec2` option, as this maintains the most consistency across the board (minus not being able to use new/delete, but malloc and free do work as expected). I suppose your solution is the correct one, only that it has to be implemented at the library level and there isn't really anything you can do at the consumer level

Answer (score 0):

You can define `vec2` as a template class and use an enum flag to represent its storage type.

```
enum class data_type {
  position, velocity, acceleration
};

template<data_type>
struct vec2 {
  float x, y;
};

vec2<data_type::position> p;
vec2<data_type::velocity> v;
vec2<data_type::acceleration> a;
```

Comment: That is indeed a solution if you yourself control the implementation, but in the case where you don't then this would break any future compatibility with the library